# React Automatically Press Button

Tags: reactjs, react-router

While setting up the authentication , I came across a problem i.e, I can only trigger the authentication if I trigger it through a button.

So ,  I woulld love to know if t here was a way to automatically trigger a button's Onclick event in React.

```
render() {
const { isAuthenticated } = this.props.auth;

return (
 <div>
   {
     !isAuthenticated() && (
      <Button
      bsStyle="primary"
      className="btn-margin"
      onClick={this.login.bind(this)}
    >
      Login
    </Button>
     )
   }
   { 
     isAuthenticated() && (
      <Button
      bsStyle="primary"
      className="btn-margin"
      onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}
    >
      Logout
    </Button>
     ) 
   }
 </div>
  );
  }
```

The above code is my render method and I want to automatically trigger the Log In Button!

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: It seems weird Oren. You should be able to call this.login and this.logout - outside of the button. The button is merely calling these functions. What’s preventing you from calling the functions independently?

Comment: Yes, I can call these functions independently, but my authentication acts very wierd when I do this, hence I wanted to know if I can autoclick  the button.

Comment: I would tell you if I knew off the top of my head. I don’t. I’m sure it rarely if ever comes up outside of a testing framework. Again - I would look into what causes your weird authentication. It seems like a bad idea to bury the problem with an artificial click. There should be no difference between clicking the button and calling one of these functions based on your code above.

Comment: Yea, I better figure out the authentication problem then I guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that using `JSX` you need to use `componentWillReceieProps()`

```
componentWillReceieProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.auth !== this.props.auth && this.props.auth){
        this.logout();
    }else if(nextProps.auth !== this.props.auth && !this.props.auth){
        this.login();
    }
}
```